# oracle database files with separate output in separate unix file

Tags: oracle, unix

In a shell script I'm connecting to DB and then want to execute some SQL code from `.sql` files:

```sh
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@$DB <<EOF 
@file1.sql > file1.txt
@file2.sql > file2.txt
EOF
```

i.e. I would like to have output of the commands in `file1.sql` in `file1.txt` 
and `file2.sql` in `file2.txt`.

This does not work, any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Fixe code blocks, grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you may try this

```
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@$DB @file1.sql > file1.txt
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@$DB @file2.sql > file2.txt
```

**OR**

create a new `file_all.sql`

```
spool file1.txt 
@file1.sql 
spool off
spool file2.txt 
@file2.sql 
spool off
```

and run

```
sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@$DB @file_all
```

Comment: I don't want to connect to db every time to execute every single file, and any other way than spooling ??

Comment: No, @Roger, spooling is the right way to do what you want.

Comment: @designer-analyst I already tried spooling...I   thought there can be another possible ways that I'm not aware of,